# Subclassing Python Enum with `auto()`, string values, and an extra property

Tags: python, enums

I have an Enum subclass that I would like to do two things:

1. Use the lowercased name of the enum as the value for each item and a property called `function`. I don't want to have to type this out each time, so I'm using `auto()`.
2. Optionally, allow the user to pass a custom function name that overrides the lowercased name.

Here is the code I have come up with to do that:

```python
from enum import Enum, auto


class LowerNameEnum(Enum):
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
        print(f"{name=}")
        return name.lower()


class Task(str, LowerNameEnum):
    def __new__(cls, value, function=None):
        obj = str.__new__(cls, value)
        obj._value_ = value

        obj.function = function or "generic_function"

        return obj

    DO_SOMETHING = auto()
    DO_SOMETHING_ELSE = auto()
    DO_ANOTHER_THING = auto(), "do_it_do_it"
    THING_4 = auto()


for t in Task:
    print(t)
    print("  ", t.value)
    print("  ", t.function)
```

But when I run this, I get the following:

```
$ python myenum.py
name='DO_SOMETHING'
name='DO_SOMETHING_ELSE'
name='THING_4'
Task.DO_SOMETHING
   do_something
   generic_function
Task.DO_SOMETHING_ELSE
   do_something_else
   generic_function
Task.DO_ANOTHER_THING
   <enum.auto object at 0x103000160>
   do_it_do_it
Task.THING_4
   thing_4
   generic_function
```

When I try to use the `auto()` value in combination with the extra argument, I get what looks like a `__repr__` of an `enum.auto` object instead of the lowercased item name. This is because `_generate_next_value_` isn't even called for this one, despite my having passed `auto()`.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Update:** Well, it turns out that `value` in the `__new__` method for the third item is an `enum.auto` object. So that's how it's getting set as the value. I can use `isinstance` to capture this, which is good. But then my question becomes: how do I find out the name of the item at this point so I can pass it to `_generate_next_value_`? Or is there some better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until this is fixed ([in 3.12](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/93464)), you'll need to use `aenum`:

```
from aenum import Enum

...

class Task(str, LowerNameEnum):
    ...
    DO_ANOTHER_THING = auto(function="do_it_do_it")
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: OK, thanks for letting me know this is on the roadmap.